# Concat 2 columns in a new phrase column using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id_sin':['s123','s124','s125','s126','s127'],
                   'num1':[12,10,23,6,np.nan],
                   'num2':['BG','TC','AB','RC',np.nan],
                   'fr':[1,1,1,1,0],
})
>>> df
   fr id_sin  num1 num2
0   1   s123    12   BG
1   1   s124    10   TC
2   1   s125    23   AB
3   1   s126     6   RC
4   0   s127   NaN  NaN
```

I want to concatenate the columns `num1` & `num2` *(num2 is num1)* in a phrase like this with fr being 1:

```
   fr id_sin  num1 num2    phrase
0   1   s123    12   BG  BG is 12
1   1   s124    10   TC  TC is 10
2   1   s125    23   AB  AB is 23
3   1   s126     6   RC   RC is 6
```

I tried this but doesn't work:

```
df['phrase'] = str(df['num2']) + ' is ' + str(df['num1'])
```

Comment: `df['num2'].astypr(str) + ' is ' + df['num21].astypr(str)`

Comment: df[['num1','num2']].apply(lambda x :f"{x[0]}is{x[1]}",1)

Comment: "Didn't work" isn't useful.  What happened? Did you reassign using `df['phrase'] = ...`?

Comment: @SabiriS, if you post the Error you get, others can help you solve it. Please post it in your Question (not in a comment) with proper formatting, so that it is clear to all readers

Comment: Someone answered, thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**:
if you want `num1` has no decimal `.0`, convert it to `Int64`:

```
df.num1 = df.num1.astype('Int64')

Out[32]:
  id_sin  num1 num2  fr
0   s123    12   BG   1
1   s124    10   TC   1
2   s125    23   AB   1
3   s126     6   RC   1
4   s127   NaN  NaN   0
```

Try `Series.str.cat`

```
df.num2.str.cat(df.num1.astype(str), sep=' is ')

Out[2055]:
0    BG is 12
1    TC is 10
2    AB is 23
3     RC is 6
4         NaN
Name: num2, dtype: object
```

---

On @rafael comment. His works, Just the typo in it causing error. It is:

```
dn['num2'].astype(str) + ' is ' + dn['num1'].astype(str)
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for, how can I remove the .0 at the end of numbers? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm!

Comment: @SabiriS: I'm glad I could be of help.